# Varaible declared is not defined in spec while testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Here is my actual AzureService

```
declare var WindowsAzure;
declare var config;

@Injectable()
export class AzureService {
    azureUrl;
    client: any;
    programmes: Programme[];
    selectedProgramme: Programme;
    orderSummary: Order;

    constructor() {
        this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(this.azureUrl);}
}
```

Here is my dashboard spec

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DashbaordComponent,
        StatusComponent
      ],
      providers:[ AzureService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashbaordComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Dashboard component contractor where i am injecting azure service:

```
constructor(private azureService: AzureService) { }
```

The test is failing stating that i have not defined WindowAzure, but where am i suppose to define?

here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables at the module level

```
declare var WindowsAzure;
declare var config;
@NgModule({...})
```

So that it is shared across the components,services.

Also import them where ever you are using as

```
import { WindowsAzure } from '../azure.service.ts'
```

Comment: Thanks @Aravind. after implementing, Cannot read property `MobileServiceClient` of undefined

Comment: `WindowsAzure` is a variable which you declared. so how will it contain any properties or methods.

Comment: WindowsAzure i am getting it from `<script src="//zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0.js"></script>` client. I am not defining.