# Global scope Variable declared is not defined in test spec while testing using jasmine and karma

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, components, karma-runner

I have created an Injectable with a declaration for a global variable in the same file to be used. I am able to get it working in the code. But in my tests the declaration is failing with an undefined error.

```
declare var myGlobal;

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor() {
    console.log(myGlobal);
  }
}
```

I am testing a component and this service is needed as a provider in the testbed for the component testing.

Following is how it is called:

```
    @Component({
    ...
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    constructor(_h: HttpService) {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._h.fileUrl = window.location.href;
        this.getSettings(this._h.settingsSrc);
    }
}
```

Following is the declaration of the service in the test

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const settingsFile = 'json';
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MenubarComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpService
      ],
    }).compileComponents();}))


it('getSettings() tests', inject([HttpService], async(async (_h: HttpService) => {
     const cmp = new AppComponent(_h);
     await cmp.ngOnInit(); // this is where the service function is trigered
}))
```

I have seen this [Varaible declared is not defined in spec while testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611879/varaible-declared-is-not-defined-in-spec-while-testing) but is not of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Karma test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263586/global-variables-in-karma-test-runner)

Answer (score 5):

You either declare that **global variable** within your test file

```
const global = "something";

describe('My test suit', function() {
...
});
```

or add a Javascript file where it's defined to your **karma.conf.js** file:

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser

```
files: [
   ...,
   'global-variable.js'
],
```

Comment: Let me try the second. Somehow the first solution failed for me.